# Jquery fade in only once

Tags: jquery, fadein

This question is very similar to another one but the solution doesn't seem to work for me. I am trying to just fade in the homepage once per visit with this code. However, the page loads instantly with no fade in.

```
<script>
$(function () {
    if ($.cookie("loaded") != "true") {
        $(".container, .footer").hide().delay(0).fadeIn(2000);
        $.cookie("loaded", "true");
    }
});
</script>
```

My initial code actually works but lacks the condition I want:

```
$(".container , .footer").hide().delay(0).fadeIn(2000);
```

Comment: What does your CSS look like? Suspect that you may not have the dom elements hidden to start with; you'd then need to run this through $(document).ready() in order to do it /after/ the page has loaded.

Comment: Make a jsfiddle with all of your code in it (HTML CSS and JS) so we can see the entire problem

Comment: I thought the jquery was hiding it? Because this $(".container , .footer").hide().delay(0).fadeIn(2000); actually works on its own just not within that if statement

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you're trying to compare undefined with a string.

Try setting the cookie to a variable and testing for undefined or "true"

```
<script>
$(function () {
var wasLoaded = $.cookie("loaded");
if (typeof wasLoaded === "undefined" || wasLoaded != "true") {
$(".container , .footer").hide().delay(0).fadeIn(2000);
$.cookie("loaded", "true");
 }
});
</script>
```

Edit: I forgot to add "typeof"